# Any way to update Google form data to match sheet row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using the edit URL to edit form entries submitted via Google forms but I've noticed if I make a change on the sheet it won't be reflected in the Google form edit URL.  Is there any way to sync the data to the form after making updates directly to the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Form, the Spreadsheet only stores the responses. Any changes on the Spreadsheet are not reflected on the form, nor can they be updated. If you change the name of a header, or add values to the sheet, the form will ultimately overwrite them, or if you add a new row, will write onto the next row. But headers and columns should not be updated directly in the sheet.